# How to find anybody's big boss

Tags: sql-server-2012

i have a problem on sql-server 2012 in T-SQL.
query to find anybody's biggest boss?

**Example:**

```
            Alex(1)
    --------------------
    Jhon(2)          Kevin(3)
------------------------------
Mike(4) Amanda(5)  Tom(6) Jery(7)


declare @t table(EMPLOYEE_ID Int,
MANAGER_ID Int,
EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200))
insert @t values(1,null,'Alex'),(2,1,'Jhon'),(3,1,'Kevin'),
(4,2,'Mike'),(5,2,'Amanda'),(6,3,'Tom'),(7,3,'Jerry')
```

i expect as result 'Alex' on following queries:

```
select T1.Employee_Name from @T as T1 inner join @T as T2 on T1.Employee_ID = T2.Manager_ID where T2.Employee_Name = 'Kevin'

select T1.Employee_Name from @T as T1 inner join @T as T2 on T1.Employee_ID = T2.Manager_ID where T2.Employee_Name = 'Tom'
```

The second query gives not the desired result ('Alex') but how to write a query which gives 'Alex' even if we add some employee's in 4. or 5. hierarchy?

Is this a task for a CTE?

Answer, many thanks to **Kaf**:

```
declare @t table(EMPLOYEE_ID Int,
MANAGER_ID Int,
EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200))
insert @t values(1,null,'Alex'),(2,1,'Jhon'),(3,1,'Kevin'),
(4,2,'Mike'),(5,2,'Amanda'),(6,3,'Tom'),(7,3,'Jerry'),
(8,null,'Sasha'),(9,8,'Jimmy'),(10,9,'Ivy')

--To get top level manager of a given person
;with cte as
(
    select employee_id, manager_id, employee_name, topmanager_id = NULL
    from @t t where manager_id is not null
    union all
    select cte.employee_id, t.manager_id, t.employee_name, cte.manager_id
    from @t t join cte on t.employee_id = cte.manager_id

)
select c.employee_name, c.topmanager_id, t.*
from cte c inner join @t as t on t.employee_id = c.employee_id
where c.manager_id is null;
```

Output:

```
employee_name   topmanager_id   EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID  EMPLOYEE_NAME
Sasha   8   10  9   Ivy
Sasha   8   9   8   Jimmy
Alex    1   7   3   Jerry
Alex    1   6   3   Tom
Alex    1   5   2   Amanda
Alex    1   4   2   Mike
Alex    1   3   1   Kevin
Alex    1   2   1   Jhon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
--To get top level manager of a given person
;with cte as
(
    select employee_id, manager_id, employee_name
    from t  where employee_name = 'Tom'
    union all
    select t.employee_id, t.manager_id, t.employee_name
    from t join cte on t.employee_id = cte.manager_id

)
select employee_id, manager_id, employee_name
from cte
where manager_id is null;
```

**[Fiddle demo for all queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9025b/28)**

```
--To Get all the managers with at least one subordinate
select t1.employee_id, t1.manager_id, t1.employee_name
from t t1
where exists (select manager_id 
              from t 
              where t.manager_id =  t1.employee_id
              ) ;

--To get top level manager(s)
select t1.employee_id, t1.manager_id, t1.employee_name
from t t1
where exists (select manager_id 
              from t 
              where t.manager_id =  t1.employee_id
              ) 
and t1.manager_id is null
```

Comment: THX but i don't agree with the results. replace where employee_name = 'Tom' with  manager_id is not null and you get nearby my desired output but without the names of the employee's...

Comment: You said `I expect 'Alex' on following queries:`. In my first query you can change the employee_name to any employees name to get the top most level manager's record.

Comment: I know it is very hard to question. I got it: i replaced in the cte select t.employee_id with select cte.employee_id to get the desired employee_id for the hole list. Finally with a additional join between cte and t to get the output.